# How to achieve this image effect with css?

Tags: css, image

[image]

Quick question: how to recreate this shadowish border effect on images with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing a subtlety, this is as simple as adding a `border` to the `img` and `padding` it by a set amount, and finishing it with a [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) that adds the 'faded' effect.

The snippet below shows an example of this:

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
```

On closer inspection of the image you supplied, it might appear there's no border, in which case just remove the `border` styling from the CSS.  The `box-shadow` will still apply arround the `padding`:

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
```